# How to implement google material tab

Tags: java, xml, android-layout

Hi coders I would like you to help me know the name of this type of tab in the image below and how to implement it I tried searching google but to no avail please help[image: Tabs found on Android 9 default dailer app]

Comment: Where did you find this tab? What app?

Comment: What's wrong with the material tabs in the Material Components Library?

Comment: The tab is found on Android 9 default dialer app
Currently am working with the tabs like that found on whatapp but I want to chance to google material tab

Comment: What device are you using?

Comment: Am using Itel A56 pro powered by android 9 go edition

Comment: As far as I'm aware this doesn't have the default Android skin, the Google dialer doesn't look like this. But anyway like I've said, the Material Components tabs would produce this exact result so I'm not sure what your problem is with them?